# negative/minus operator in case statement

Tags: postgresql, operators, case

I'm currently trying to understand some code and for the life of me I can't figure out what the negative/minus operator is doing inside of the CASE statement. When I try removing it, it breaks the visualization.

This is part of a bigger puzzle of figuring out exactly what this portion of the query does. I know it's a counter of some sort that checks the year, and if the year is 2017, then extracts the month. If it isn't 2017, then it extracts the month 12 months from now, but I'm not sure how it works beyond that. Any insight into the negative/minus operators in this CASE statement or this function in general would be appreciated.

```
MAX(
CASE WHEN (- CASE WHEN EXTRACT(year FROM premium_creation_date) = 2017  --?? some sort of counter
                    THEN EXTRACT(month FROM premium_creation_date) 
                    ELSE 
                        EXTRACT(month FROM premium_creation_date) + 12 
                    END 
            + CASE WHEN EXTRACT(year FROM user_creation_date) = 2017 
                    THEN EXTRACT(month FROM user_creation_date) 
                    ELSE 
                        EXTRACT(month FROM user_creation_date) + 12 
                    END
            ) = 1
        THEN unique_user_count
        ELSE 
            NULL 
END
) AS restriction
```

Comment: ... and what about telling us which manuals didn't work for you when you tried to find out the answer yourself? Now its a bit asking for a weblink to a manual... please show effort in solving it yourself first before posing this question.

Comment: @ZF007 I tried searches like "case negative operator" "case minus operator" and the like for a good 20-30 minutes but kept on getting irrelevant information regarding `case` use in SQL. I only later realized that it was just a poorly written arithmetic calculation and not a special addendum to `case` syntax in particular.

Comment: @ZF007 I appreciate the pointers though. I'll be sure to lay out exactly what search terms didn't work for me and why they didn't in the future.

Comment: "thumbs up" and Enjoy SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-` changes the sign of the result of the `CASE`.

The `CASE` gives the month of the `premium_creation_date` when the year of that date is 2017. Otherwise it's the month plus 12.

So e.g. `2017-05-04` yields 5 in the `CASE`, which makes -5 after the `-` took effect. For `2018-07-06` that would be 7 + 12 = 19 and therefore -19.

Actually you could turn this whole thing around and subtract the first `CASE` from the second. That may look clearer.

Comment: Oh wow, that makes a lot of sense. I still thought they kept the actual name of the month which was confusing to me. Do you happen to know why it would equal 1?


What seemed also nonintuitive was that there's a `MAX()` too since there's nothing that it's taking the maximum of, aside from the `unique_user_count` counter.

Comment: @davviid: No I don't. How would I? I don't know what this is for or where it came from, neither the logic behind this.